# How calculate $\int_{\mathbb R} \chi(x-j)\chi\left(\frac{x-u}{t}\right)\, e^{i\,\xi \,x}\, dx$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function?

Tags: integration

Let us consider the function $\chi(x)$ which is $1$ in the range $[-1/2,1/2]$ and $0$ outside it. Let $t>0$, $j\in \mathbb N$, $\xi,u\in\mathbb R$. Calculate the integral:
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \chi(x-j)\chi\left(\frac{x-u}{t}\right)\, e^{i\,\xi \,x}\, dx$$
I don't really have an approach to evaluate this integral. Someone has an idea?

Comment: Why can't you apply the standard tricks?

Comment: @blamethelag: Do you mean to use the definition of $\chi$?

Comment: Yes, maybe try to rewrite the integral using your idea.